# How to find common matches for different column values in SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, aliases

I have the following table "Friends":

[image]

The goal is to find out how many users have the exact same list of friends.
In this case, the result would be user_id 1 and user_id 4 since both user 1 and user 4 are friends with "2" and "3".

[image]

I think I am on the right track by using the code below:

`SELECT * FROM Friends A, Friends B WHERE A.friend_id=B.friend_id AND A.user_id <> B.user_id`

[image]

However, I am not able to figure out how to finish the query so that it calculates the matching list of friends. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do not use comma, use INNER JOIN, this method is obsolete from 1995. Also provide what SQL are you using.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide your SQL type.

For MySQL, you can group concat the friends for every user and cross by this value. The default is ",". Then join the same table to compare by the same list of friends.

```
SELECT t1.friends, t1.friends FROM
(
SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(friend_id) as friends
FROM friends
GROUP BY friend_id
) as t1
JOIN

(
SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(friend_id) as friends
FROM friends
GROUP BY friend_id
) as t2
on t1.friends = t2.friends
```

Comment: @AATU if my answer helps you, please upvote and mark it as correct. Thanks in advance